# Executor service threads, some local connection object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a task, which uses some connection. By nature the connection should be affined to a thread i.e. thread which creates the connection, is the only thread which uses it.

Now my runnable task is supposed to use this connection, what I am not sure is how do I initialise threads with some connection and tell Runnable to use it?

MyThread.java

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
     Connection conn = new Connection();
     MyThread() {super();}
}
```

MyRunnable.java

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
     Mydata data;
     MyRunnable(Mydata  data) {this.data = data}
     void run() {
       // use data, need to use conn as well. Not sure how????
     }
}
```

Comment: You could use [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to manage connections. You need a little more context for a more complete answer though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to write a poor-mans connection pool. One way to manage the task of getting a connection is to use a ThreadLocal.

```
ThreadLocal<Connection> connections = ThreadLocal.withInitial(ConnectionFactor::create);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

Then when you run a task you can grab a connection.

```
void submitTask(Data d){
    executor.submit( ()->{
        Connection con = connections.get();
        //you have a connection and the data. 
    }
}
```

Should a connection be tied to the life of a thread? What about closing a connection? What if a connection gets closed?

A `ForkJoinPool` lets you follow the life of your threads.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConnectionPoolForSO{
    static ThreadLocal<Connection> connections = new ThreadLocal<>();
    static class ConnectWorkerThread extends ForkJoinWorkerThread{
        public ConnectWorkerThread( ForkJoinPool pool){
            super(pool);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onStart(){
            connections.set( new Connection());
        }
        @Override
        protected void onTermination( Throwable exception ){
            System.out.println("terminating");
            Connection c = connections.get();
            c.close();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ForkJoinPool executor = new ForkJoinPool(5, ConnectWorkerThread::new, ( t, e ) -> e.printStackTrace(), true  );

        List<ForkJoinTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
            final int data = i;
            tasks.add( 
                executor.submit( ()->{
                    System.out.println(data + " working with: " + connections.get().name + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName() );
                } ) 
            );

        }
        for(ForkJoinTask task: tasks) task.get();

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}

class Connection{
    String name;
    public Connection(){
        this.name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

    public void close(){

        System.out.println("closed: " + name + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

This will fire up worker threads as necessary to do the work. When a new thread is created a new Connection is create, then they get re-used. Finally when the thread is no-longer in use the connection is closed.

These connections lack a property that a real connection might have, they close. So you would need yet another method.

```
static Connection getConnection(){
    Connection c = connections.get();
    if(!checkConnection(c)){
        c = new Connection();
        connections.set(c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

This might be a start, but I hope you can see some of the remaining holes. The uncaught exception handler? The throwable passed to `onTermination`?

I would recommend looking for a connection pool library.